# How to write a valid boolean conditional in objective-c using objectForKey

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements, boolean

I'm seeking to understand why the following always hits the ELSE clause.  What I can't figure out is that regardless of the actual value ( NSLog shows a 0 or 1) this always hits the else.  Any reason why?

The item NSArray is pulled from a JSON object -fyi

```
BOOL* instock = [item objectForKey:@"itemInStock"];
    obj.instock = instock;
    NSLog(@"and it was %@", obj.instock);
    if (obj.instock == YES) {
      //do yes stuff
    }else {
      //do no stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code here is rather strange. What is the type of `obj.instock`? Your very first line

```
BOOL* instock = [item objectForKey:@"itemInStock"];
```

makes no sense at all. `-objectForKey:` doesn't return `BOOL*` values. It returns `id`. I'm guessing here that you're actually getting an `NSNumber *` back, and it just happens to work alright because an `NSNumber *` fits inside of a `BOOL *` (as they are both pointers). Similarly, `obj.instock` is likely to be an `NSNumber*` as well (if it wasn't an object of some sort, your `NSLog()` would crash).

So, assuming that `obj.instock` is an `NSNumber*`, the conditional you want is simply

```
if ([obj.instock boolValue]) {
    // yes
} else {
    // no
}
```

You should also fix this code to not try and claim you have a `BOOL*` when you don't.

Answer (score 1):

In your `NSLog`, you are using `%@`.
`%@` refers to objects. Contrary to your `BOOL* instock` which is not an object.

There are ways to fix that.
What data type does your `[item objectForKey:@"itemInStock"];` return?
If it returns an NSNumber for example, then you can do:

```
obj.instock = [[item objectForKey:@"itemInStock"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"and it was %d", obj.instock);
if (obj.instock == YES) {
  //do yes stuff
}else {
  //do no stuff
}
```

Again, there are other ways to do that.

Comment: Assuming his posted code doesn't crash, `obj.instock` is not a `BOOL` but rather an `id` (likely an `NSNumber*`). In that case, your posted code won't work.

Comment: @Kevin: First, How do you know his `obj.instock` is not `BOOL`? All of us don't know what data type `obj.instock` is because there was no declaration at all. And second, what my code implies is `obj.instock` is declared as `BOOL` datatype.

Comment: If `obj.instock` was `BOOL`, then the `NSLog` in the original code would have crashed. That's why I qualified my statement with "Assuming his posted code doesn't crash".